# Why the count of IO-APIC-edge timer showed in /proc/interrupts does not change often?

Tags: linux-kernel

I run `cat /proc/interrupts` on CentOS 6.5 with a `2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64` kernel. The result is

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:      31039          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
// content omitted
LOC:  211509915  178638855  154577696  153050202   Local timer interrupts
// content omitted
```

Then I run `cat /proc/interrupts` several times. But the count `31039` of IO-APIC-edge timer interrupt does not change. My first question is whether IO-APIC-edge timer represents the global timer which interrupts HZ times every second. If yes, why its count does not change HZ times every second?

I run `grep CONFIG_HZ /boot/*config*`, it shows `CONFIG_HZ=1000`.

My second question is why only CPU0 receives the timer interrupts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On a SMP machine with local APIC, global timer is only used during boot time. After local APIC is setup up, local timer interrupts both call update_process_times and update jiffies. The global timer is unused. All CPUs perform update_process_times. But only one CPU updates jiffies.

Answer to my first question: IO-APIC-edge timer represents the global timer. But it is only used during boot time. Since it is unused after boot time, its count does not change HZ times every second.

Answer to my second question: Only one CPU handles the interrupts, other CPUs ignores it:

```
if cpuid == cpu_for_global_timer
    handle it
else
    ignore it
```

For details, refer to http://yaojingguo.github.io/Linux-Kernel-Time.html

Answer (score 1):

`timer` is the <strike>good</strike> old ISA timer interrupt; it is used only when booting, until the kernel has detected and initialized the local APIC timers.

Every CPU (core) uses a `HZ` timer for scheduling.
However, with `CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE` or even `CONFIG_NO_HZ`, that timer is disabled when it is not needed.
In this case, only one CPU needs a timer for timekeeping.